# Form requested url not found

Tags: post, request, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

hello
Im working on a symfony project.
Im battleling with a form that wont redirect to its own page. the action attribute is set to "" and method set to post. In that case it should call the same page but im ending on a 404 page.
 here's the code of my page in the action file:

```
public function executeDetail(sfWebRequest $request)
 {




    if($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST))
    {

            if(!$this->getUser()->isAuthenticated())
                    $this->redirect('@user_login');

            $formData = $request->getParameter($this->form->getName());

        $this->form->bind($formData, $request->getFiles($this->form->getName()));

                if ($this->form->isValid())
        {
            $user = $this->getUser()->getLogged();  

            $comment = $this->form->save();
                    $comment->setIsActive(1);
                    $comment->setAuthor($user);
                    $comment->setHash(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
                    $comment->setArticle($this->detail);
                    $comment->save();

                    $this->status = 'SUCCESS';



        }
        else
        {
            $this->status = 'ERROR';
        }

    }
             $this->story = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
        $this->status = false;
        $this->bAuthorLogged = false;
    $this->form = new ArticleCommentForm();
    }
```

what is funny is when i call the page from it's url it's correctly show up, 404 only appens when submiting with the form.
i hope this speaks to somebody
 thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Do define your form opening tag like this in your view:

```
<?php echo $form->renderFormTag($sf_request->getUri()) ?>
```

2) check if your route accept your http method (post/put):
call from bash in your app directory:

```
./symfony app:routes frontend
```

Youll see all your routes and theres definitions (with accepted http methods)

3) you can define it in Your routing:

```
route_name:
  url:        /my-nice-url
  param:    { module: yourModuleName, action: detail }
  requirements:
    # this is what matters - if you leave it undefined, it shlould accept any HTTP method
    sf_method: [get, post, put, delete]
```

This is very good info source about configs:
http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/