# Symfony - Form requested url not found

Tags: php, post, request, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

Im working on a symfony project. Im battleling with a form that won't redirect to its own page. The action attribute is set to "" and method set to post. In that case it should call the same page but I'm ending on a 404 page.

Here's the code of my page in the action file:

public function executeDetail(sfWebRequest $request)
 {

```
if($request->isMethod(sfRequest::POST))
{

        if(!$this->getUser()->isAuthenticated())
                $this->redirect('@user_login');

        $formData = $request->getParameter($this->form->getName());

    $this->form->bind($formData, $request->getFiles($this->form->getName()));

            if ($this->form->isValid())
    {
        $user = $this->getUser()->getLogged();  

        $comment = $this->form->save();
                $comment->setIsActive(1);
                $comment->setAuthor($user);
                $comment->setHash(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
                $comment->setArticle($this->detail);
                $comment->save();

                $this->status = 'SUCCESS';



    }
    else
    {
        $this->status = 'ERROR';
    }

}
         $this->story = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
    $this->status = false;
    $this->bAuthorLogged = false;
$this->form = new ArticleCommentForm();
}
```

The funny thing is that when I call the page from it's url it's correctly show up, 404 only happens when submitting with the form.

Thanks in advance

PS: routing config is:

```
stories_detail:
  url:   /stories-of-the-month/:slug
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  param: { module: stories, action: detail}
  options: { model: Article, type: object, method: doSelectForSlug }
```

Comment: Can you post your routing configuration?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited the post you can find it there.

Comment: Are you sure that in your form the url action is correctly created?

Comment: Try comparing the working URL and the URL from which you get a 404. If they are identical, then it has to be a routing issue. you don't have a method requirement on your url, so I'm out of ideas as to what could be wrong there.

Comment: Just the same problem like i answered here, check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699173/form-requested-url-not-found/8711703#8711703

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly allow POST for the route. Change your route to:

```
stories_detail:
  url:   /stories-of-the-month/:slug
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  param: { module: stories, action: detail}
  options: { model: Article, type: object, method: doSelectForSlug }
  requirements: 
    sf_method: [get, post]
```