# POSTing to sfDoctrineRoute

Tags: symfony1, url-routing, http-post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Symfony - Form requested url not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705889/symfony-form-requested-url-not-found)

I'm working on a symfony project.
I'm battleling with a form that won't redirect to its own page. The action attribute is set to "" and method set to post. In that case it should call the same page but I'm ending on the 404 page.

What is funny is when i call the page from it's url it's correctly show up, 404 only appens when submiting the form.
When I run: `php symfony app:routes frontend` in my shell, it says the method is set to head and get. But it's not even set in the routing.yml and if i make a requirement any in the routing, 404 still show up. Here's my routing:

```
stories_detail:
  url:   /stories-of-the-month/:slug
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  param: { module: stories, action: detail}
  options: { model: Article, type: object, method: doSelectForSlug } 
  requirements: 
    sf_method: any
```

How can i make my page accept the post method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `sfDoctrineRoute` objects only accept get/head requests, this is a common pitfall for beginners. This is the correct requirement:

```
sf_method: [get, post]
```